# View historic USD prices when transactions were made

Tags: transactions, blockchain, value

Currently when viewing blockchain.info transactions, all transaction values are quoted in today's price. But is there an option or service where you can see how much the value was at the time of the transaction? Example, Say I send Alice 1 BTC 2 years ago. At today's price it will look like I sent $4000, but 2 years ago it was sub $1000. Is there a blockexplorer that shows the historic price value?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for similar solution and have come up with a manual one.

Note: you need to know the Bitcoin address of the sender and receiver, or transaction hash. let us suppose we know a bitcoin wallet address

> 3BtSyeNf24tEXkEYKiMmDjM98W7Yqudh3w

and it belongs to person A, following steps can be executed to know about the transaction details

Step 1: Goto www.blockchain.info and enter the respective address into website's search bar.

Step 2: resulting page will show transaction details which are as follows

```
      a. Transactions performed = 2
      b. Total Received = 0.02608688 BTC
      c. Final balance = 0 BTC
```

[explanation: Respective Address had two Transactions, 1st. it received 0.02608688 and it spent complete amount because its remaining balance is 0 BTC. Each transactions is explained below.]

Step 3: Evaluating transactions

```
      a. **First Transaction** hash is 
         0d704a15bd8d56812dff9d067c0510afb4185190d2816513dd8eca777b7ec72c
      b. This transaction was confirmed at 2017-10-09 16:08:56
      c. Using historic Bitcoin price reference at coindesk.com/price/,it
         was found that at that moment 1 BTC was equal to 4722 USD.
      d. Hence, first transaction shows that person A received 123 USD 
         worth of bitcoin. (0.02609 BTC * 4722 USD = 123 USD)

      e. **Second Transaction** hash is 
         fe5bd13f81d26166937efc472f8a30090e7f30e721517ad212bc06e48f8e1e96
      f. This transaction was confirmed at 2017-10-15 16:05:17
      g. Using historic Bitcoin price reference at coindesk.com/price/,it
         was found that at that moment 1 BTC was equal to 5700 USD.
      h. Hence, Second transaction shows that person A transfered 
         accumulated BTC for 148 USD . 
         (0.02609 BTC * 5700 USD = 148 USD).
```

Step 3: Net difference

```
      a. Person A gained 20% in 6 days (one perspective)
      b. Net worth of holding is zero because wallet holds 0 BTC
```

I hope i cleared some of the confusion.